# ¿Cómo leo un arreglo para que acumule la lista de valores del arreglo?

Tags: c#

Tengo un proyecto de consola en C#, lo estoy haciendo en Visual Studio 2017.

El ejercicio que tengo que hacer consiste en obtener el promedio general de un curso de 10 alumnos donde cada uno tiene 4 notas. Para resolver esto cree una clase llamada NOTAS en donde donde creo el un arreglo bidimensional tipo `double[10,4]` y creé un método que lea las notas ingresadas del arreglo para que, con un acumulador, vaya guardando y sumando las notas. Y en la clase `PROGRAM` debería pedirle al usuario que ingrese los valores del arreglo, luego creería yo, tendría que llamar el arreglo y el método para resolverlo.

Sin embargo el programa me arroja un par de errores en la clase `NOTAS` y no entiendo que pasa. Ya he consultado un par de libros y paginas web pero no encuentro una solución.

Les adjunto lo que llevo del código que básicamente es la clase `NOTAS`.

```
namespace PROMEDIOCLASE
{
    class NOTASCLASE
    {
        private double [,] _notasalumnos = new double [10, 4];

        public double Notasalumnos
        {
        get => _notasalumnos; //aquí me sale un error que dice: no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'double[*,*]' en double.
        set => _notasalumnos = value; //aquí me sale el mismo error
        }

        public double promedio_total(double [,] Notasalumnos) //aquí en el nombre del método me sale un error que dice: no todas las rutas de acceso de código devuelven un valor
        {
        double promedio = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
           {
              for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
              {
                  promedio = promedio + Notasalumnos[i,j];
                  return promedio;
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: el problema  es que en el método `promedio_total` el `return` esta  dentro del segundo `for`, por lo cual no va a totalizar ya que finaliza la ejecución del método antes de sumar todos los elementos

Comment: Gracias Byron por tu observación, ya lo correjí sin embargo me siguen apareciendo los errores mencionados.

Comment: `public double Notasalumnos` debes cambiarlo por `public double[,] Notasalumnos`

Answer (score 1):

En tu código hay varias correcciones que hacer:

En primer lugar la propiedad `Notasalumnos` es de tipo `double`  mientras que el campo `_notasalumnos` es de tipo `double[,]`. El que está mal es el valor de retorno de la propiedad que lo debes cambiar por `doble[,]`

```
public double[,] Notasalumnos
{
    get => _notasalumnos;
    set => _notasalumnos = value;
}
```

En segundo lugar, el método `promedio_total` necesita devolver un double pero en tu código estas ejecutando el return al pasar por la cooredenada `[0,0]`. Eso no solo hace que el resultado sea incorrecto devolviendo sólo la suma y no el promedio y sólo del primer elemento, sino que además no se puede alcanzar el final de la iteración y no podiendo devolver nada en ese caso.

Ya que la lógica está incorrecta y podemos aprovechar el foreach para recorrer todos los elementos del arreglo independientemente de la cantidad de dimensiones no necesitamos hacer el doble `for` y el código puede quedar así.

```
public double promedio_total(double[,] Notasalumnos)
{
    var suma = 0.0;
    foreach (var nota in Notasalumnos)
    {
        suma += nota;
    }

    return suma / Notasalumnos.Length;
}
```

Además no necesitas pasarle como parámetro al método `promedio_total` el arreglo de notas porque ya es una propiedad de la misma clase, simplemente quítalo.

```
public double promedio_total()
{
    var suma = 0.0;
    foreach (var nota in Notasalumnos)
    {
        suma += nota;
    }

    return suma / Notasalumnos.Length;
}
```

Hasta este punto el código ya está corregido y quedaría así:

```
namespace PROMEDIOCLASE
{
    class NOTASCLASE
    {
        private double[,] _notasalumnos = new double[10, 4];

        public double[,] Notasalumnos
        {
            get => _notasalumnos;
            set => _notasalumnos = value;
        }

        public double promedio_total()
        {
            var suma = 0.0;
            foreach (var nota in Notasalumnos)
            {
                suma += nota;
            }

            return suma / Notasalumnos.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero quisiera sugerirte algunas cosas más:

Ya que el getter y setter no están haciendo nada mas que devolver el valor del campo subyacente se puede simplificar de esta manera. Ten en cuenta que ya no necesitamos el campo y la inicialización de la propiedad se puede hacer en la misma línea:

```
namespace PROMEDIOCLASE
{
    class NOTASCLASE

        public double[,] Notasalumnos { get; set; } = new double[10, 4];

        public double promedio_total()
        {
            var suma = 0.0;
            foreach (var nota in Notasalumnos)
            {
                suma += nota;
            }

            return suma / Notasalumnos.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Finalmente tu sugiero seguir las convenciones de nomenclatura de clases, namespaces, campos, propiedades parámetros, etc.

Con lo cual el código quedaría así:

```
namespace PromedioClase
{
    class NotasClase
    {
        public double[,] NotasAlumnos { get; set; } = new double[10, 4];

        public double PromedioTotal()
        {
            var suma = 0.0;
            foreach (var nota in NotasAlumnos)
            {
                suma += nota;
            }

            return suma / NotasAlumnos.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Carlos lo voy a corregir a ver cómo me va.

Comment: Listo, mi respuesta ya está completa

Answer (score 0):

La definicion de la propiedad no puede ser double y el campo que estas retornando es double[,], el cual es un tipo distinto.

```
namespace MiscConsole
{
    class NOTASCLASE
    {
        public NOTASCLASE()
        {
            Notasalumnos = new double[10, 4];

        }
       ///En C# 7 seria como lo indicas pero la en lugar de double es double[,]

        public double[,] Notasalumnos
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double promedio_total(double[,] Notasalumnos) //aquí en el nombre del método me sale un error que dice: no todas las rutas de acceso de código devuelven un valor
        {
            double promedio = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    promedio = promedio + Notasalumnos[i, j];

                }
            }
            return promedio;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Gracias Byron pero definiendo el arreglo así el VS no lo está reconociendo.